# How do I use jQuery to trigger an event when a checkbox is checked/unchecked repeatedly?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent default checkbox event from overriding my jQuery check/uncheck function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663432/how-do-i-prevent-default-checkbox-event-from-overriding-my-jquery-check-uncheck)

I have figured out how to trigger an event when a user checks a checkbox. However, I want to trigger an event if they uncheck that same checkbox. Basically, I want to be able to check the checkbox, trigger an event, and then if I uncheck that same checkbox it should trigger another event. I want to be able to check it, then uncheck it immediately afterwards and have it trigger another event. Here is my code:

```
$('#myID').click(function() {

    var isChecked = $('#myID').is(':checked');

    if(isChecked)
    {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something Else');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myID').click(function() {
  var isChecked = this.checked; // this.checked is enough or $(this).is(':checked')
  if(isChecked) {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something');
    } else {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something Else');
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** One think should keep in mind that, when one use `$('#myField').replaceWith()`, then `#myField` will removed from DOM, so next time you can't catch it and next `replaceWith()` will fail.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/urnkt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could tag the check event back on to the checkbox with a class

```
$('#myID').click(function() {

    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var alreadyChecked = $(this).has('checked');

    if(alreadyChecked)
    {
       //fire appropriate event
    }

    if(isChecked)
    {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myField').replaceWith('Something Else');
    }

});
```

if checked at start first click will uncheck, second will check, third will fire event
if unchecked at start first click will check, second will fire event

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myID').on('change', function() {
    var something = this.checked ? 'Something' : 'Something Else';
    $('#myField').replaceWith(something);
});​
```

The problem is that you are replacing the entire `#myField` element, so the next time the function runs there is no element `#myfield`, and it's not working.
Try just replacing the contents instead, `html()`, `append()`, `prepend()` or any of the others that don't remove the entire `#myField` element will do :

```
<div id="myField">Something</div>
```

-

```
$('#myID').on('change', function() {
    var something = this.checked ? 'Something' : 'Something Else';
    $('#myField').text(something);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/CmcJE/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for trigger event of jquery so use

```
<script>
        $('#btn1').trigger('click');


        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            // do something
        });
</script>
```