# How do I prevent default checkbox event from overriding my jQuery check/uncheck function?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes inside a table with a simple jQuery function that allows the user to click anywhere in the table row to check/uncheck the checkbox. It works great, except when the user actually clicks on the checkbox. It doesn't work then. Any ideas? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<tr onClick="checkBox()">...</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
function checkBox() {

var ischecked = $('input#myContacts').attr("checked");

if(ischecked)
{
    $('input#myContacts').attr("checked", false);
}
else
{
    $('input#myContacts').attr("checked", true);
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: where is the `#myContacts` checkbox plaed? post detailed html

Comment: @John Anderson: Alexander has a point; There is more than one valid solution here. If you need further clarification please ask for it, otherwise accept an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to avoid your `input#myContacts`'s click event propagates to the `tr`'s click event. Also, I can't believe you are mixing jQuery and DOM in that way yet, when you should be using jQuery Events.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#myContacts").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: Another solution (using less script) is to make the script fire only when the label is clicked, rather than the whole row containing the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm a jQuery newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML showing why that function is triggered by it's hard to say. A jsFiddle would be helpful. Just speculation, but could it be that you click the checkbox, which checks it, but the click event immediately calls that function which unchecks it?

Comment: I just updated the code to show how I call the function from within the html.

Comment: You still haven't shown me the most important thing; Is your checkbox within the <tr>. I'm sure that it is, and that's your problem. See here to check if I have the right idea: http://jsfiddle.net/qmdGK/ . If I do, it is exactly what I suggested above, it's ticking, then (due to your script) unticking before you can see it change. The kind of fix you are looking for is to bind that click event to a <td> containing a label next to a <td> containing your checkbox, or stop the click event on the <input> bubbling up to the <tr>. To prevent bubbling: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Ran out of characters... I would try to make jsFiddles of the solution, but I am about to meet someone for a days climbing, so I don't have the time right now. Perhaps when I get back this evening (UK time) I could have a go if you still don't have a solution.

Comment: Also (strangely) I wan't able to get your code to work when the js was in the js box on jsFiddle. That may be because you are not using the $(selector).click(function) binding that is the usual way of binding events to html elements when using jquery. See here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

```
   <tr class="checkBox">...</tr>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr.checkBox').live('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
                $('input#myContacts').attr("checked", function () {
                    return !$(this).prop('checked');
                });

                //Or

                $(this).find('input#myContacts').attr("checked", function () {
                    return !$(this).prop('checked');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: http://jsfiddle.net/qmdGK/3/ (Using two table cells but only binding click to text cell)

Solution 2: http://jsfiddle.net/qmdGK/4/ (using stopPropagation() on the checkbox click event)

Both are using jQuery to bind the event to the element which is preferred.